# How to know how much battery in terms of hours and minutes is left on my phone?

Tags: battery

I want to know the remaining time of my cell phone battery. Android only gives me how much battery in terms of percentage has been consumed since the last charging.

However, what I want is to know how much more time I have before my phone goes off? How can I get that information?

Comment: The phone drains different amount of battery depending upon the state it is in like, idle, screen on, WiFi, playing Video and such. So it is difficult to predict how many hours the battery will last before dying out.

Comment: @roxan, yeah, you're right. But just like the battery of a laptop, it can give us an estimate based on the current battery usage rate. This way, I can get sure that I can continue listening to my favorite music, for another 20 minutes, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Battery Indicator Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro) or a similar alternative might help. In addition to showing the remaining battery in numbers, it also tries to "guesstimate" the remaining minutes, depending on light/medium/heavy usage.